# Can anyone provide me details/links regarding exchanges and queue in Rabbit MQ that can be used in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I need to use Rabbit MQ in Mule application for using its exchange and queue. can anyone provide me any leads?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply google and get the related links.
Anyway,
you can go through below link...I think that will be useful for you.

https://confluex.com/blog/rabbitmq-amqp-with-muleesb/